# Really slow Internet speed in Ubuntu 18.04 but not in Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless

There is a really big difference in download speeds in my PC in Ubuntu vs Windows. Linux is giving about 13Kbps whereas average speed in windows is about 2Mbps.

It maybe some driver problem.
Outputs of `lsusb` and `lsmod | grep rtl`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c83 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsmod | grep rtl 
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             552960  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`?

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the following answer and then please post the results to help us diagnose the issue. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/167115